# Real-time database get request in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I’m trying to get data from my real-time database, but apparently the function returns an empty list.

Categories is printed normally with data, but for some reason the return doesn't work. How can I fix it?

My function

```
Future<List<String>> getCategories(String roomCode) async {
  Query ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance
      .ref()
      .child("rooms/$roomCode/gameSettings/categories");

  List<String> categories = [];
  final snapshot = await ref.get();
  for (final element in snapshot.children) {
    categories.add(element.value.toString());
  }

  print(categories);
  return categories;
}
```